# index exceeding matrix dimentions

Tags: matlab, markov-chains

I was trying to get this low order recursive function in matlab. i want to calculate the probability of status of a site at next time step, given that I have the initial probability of that being a status.

```
P= Probability
x= status(0,1)
Dij= probability to pick a site
P(Status of Site(i) being x at next time step)= Summation[P(Status of Site(i) being x at previous time step)*Dij]
```

and this is what I have done! but my index always exceeds matrix dimensions! I need help with this.

```
clear all;
clc;

%function [t,i]= CopyingInfluenceModel
%%Define constants
%% generate some random weights vectori.e. the transition matrix=C
 % C=[0 (1,2) 0 (1,4) 0 0 0;
 %    (2,1) 0 (2,3) 0 0 0 0;
 %    0 (3,2) 0 (3,4) 0 0 0;
 %    (1,4) 0 (4,3) 0 (4,5) 0 0;
 %    0 0 0 (5,4) 0 (5,6) (5,7);
 %    0 0 0 0 (6,5) 0 (6,7);
 %    0 0 0 0 (7,5) (7,6) 0];
 %copying probabilities=branch weights
 onetwo=0.47;
 twothree=0.47;
 threefour=0.47;
 onefour=0.47;
 fourfive=0.023;
 fivesix=0.47;
 fiveseven=0.47;
 sixseven=0.47;
 selfweight1=0.06;
 selfweight2=0.037;
 % SourceNodes - a list of Nodes that are forced to be kept in one side of the cut.
 % WeightedGraph - symetric matrix of edge weights. Wi,j is the edge
 % connecting Nodes i,j  use Wi,j=0 or Wi,j == inf to indicate unconnected Nodes                  

 WeightedGraph=[0 onetwo 0 onefour 0 0 0;
 onetwo 0 twothree 0 0 0 0;
 0 twothree 0 threefour 0 0 0;
 onefour 0 threefour 0 fourfive 0 0;
 0 0 0 fourfive 0 fivesix fiveseven;
 0 0 0 0 fivesix 0 sixseven;
 0  0 0 0 fiveseven sixseven 0];
 Dij=sparse(WeightedGraph);


 % Initializing the variables
 t=[];
 i=[];
 %assigining the initial conditions
 t(1)=0;
 p(1)= 0.003; %% initial probability of status
 %set index no i to 1(initial condition for i=1)
 i=1;
 %repeating calculating new probabilities

 %% If the probability is zero, terminate while loop
 while p(i)>=0
    %calculate at the next time step for given index no
    t(i+1)= t(i);
    %calculate the status_probability at given time t=(i+1)
    [p(i+1)]=[p(i)]+sum([p(i)]*[Dij(i)]);
    [NextStatus(i)]= [p(i+1)]

%index i increases by 1 to calculate next probability
i=i+1;
end
```

Stack Trace is:

```
%%??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions. 
%%Error in ==> CopyingInfluenceModel at 54 
%%[p(i+1)]=[p(i)]+sum([p(i)]*[Dij(i)]);
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace along with pointing to the line of the first error?

Comment: here it is..
%%??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

    %%Error in ==> CopyingInfluenceModel at 54
        %%[p(i+1)]=[p(i)]+sum([p(i)]*[Dij(i)]);

Comment: Can you please scope this question down with an appropriately initialized P? (if the point would be just the calculation you mentioned at the beginning.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `Dij` not `p`. `Dij` has a fixed length so when `i` exceeds that the program throws an error.

Added:

I can't really see your logic in the code, but I have a strong feeling that you are calculating something wrong. `Dij` is a 7 x 7 matrix but you treat it as a vector by calling `Dij(i)`. If you are trying to multiply something by a row or column, you need the `Dij(i,:)` or `Dij(:, i)` notation.

Comment: How do I change the matlab code, inorder to make it right?
Pardon me my ignorance with matlab.
I am a new girl in this programming field.

Comment: To be honest there seems to be a lot of problems with this code. These are some of the problems: (1) you mention if probability is zero, so the `while` condition should be `p(i) > 0` (2) `p(i)` in your code is never zero because it starts as a positive number and in each iteration another positive number is added to it. (3) `Dij(i)` is a single number and so is `p(i)` so your term `[p(i)]*[Dij(i)]` -- which by the way has lots of extra brackets and is really equivalent of `p(i)*Dij(i)` -- is a single number, rendering sum() function completely useless. I'd redo the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

The logic as you posted it doesn't work, essentially, p(i+i) isn't defined yet. There are a few ways to do it, depending on if you want to keep p or not. I'll post a method that keeps p around, but some work could be done to make the code more efficient.

```
p=[p;p(i)+sum(p(i)*Dij(i))];
NextStatus(i)= p(i+1)
```

Comment: Well, this should fix your error as it is posted for a small number of iterations. If you start iterating more than 100, this code would need a re-write. There might still need to be some serious work in other ways, however...

Comment: I want to put up a simple markov chain in matlab where a network of nodes where the probability of the node i taking status m at time(t+1) can be tracked using:
    `P(Status of Site(i) being x at next time step)= Summation[P(Status of Site(i) being x at previous time step)*Dij]`